# How do I run Selenium in the background without it freezing up my GUI?

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Im creating a program that updates a website and takes screenshots of specific elements until I ask it to stop. This works fine but I want to be able to control multiple drivers from a GUI. The issue that im currently running into is that once I start up one driver from the GUI, the GUI freezes until that driver is stopped (until that piece of code stops running). How can I allow my program to let this code/driver run while it runs another piece of code/driver?

This is what happens once a start button is clicked:

```
try {
            
            stopDriver.setEnabled(true); //makes a stop button visable
            startDriver.setEnabled(false); //makes a start button invisable
            Object.start(); //Starts the process

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

This is what the .start() method does (this is inside of the Object class):

```
public static void start() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        chromeDriver.get("website"); //Goes to the website
        chromeDriver.manage().window().maximize(); //Maximizes the page
        
        Actions.Login(chromeDriver); //Logs into the website
        Object.setFilter(); //Sets a filter with parameters from the constructor
        Object.screenshot(); //Takes the screenshot
        
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

My constructor inside of the Object class:

```
public Object(int Min, int Max, double priceMin, double priceMax) {
        
        this.Min = "" + Min;
        this.Max = "" + Max;
        this.priceMin = "" + priceMin;
        this.priceMax = "" + priceMax;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        this.chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        
    }
```

Would i need to multithread my program? If so, how does one go about doing that?

Comment: What are you using for the UI? Swing, JavaFX, SWT, something else? With Swing you should check out how `SwingWorker` works, that's meant for this kind of thing.

Comment: Im using swing, ill have a look at SwingWorker. Thanks

Comment: `SwingWorker` does work very well, however my issue now is that a `SwingWorker` can only be used once. Is there something similar that can be stopped and then re-executed?

Comment: Why not just create a new `SwingWorker`? You can use the same code of course, you don't have to copy that.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing and it works fine now, thanks for the help!